# Travel to Cuba from LA for non US residents

Tags: visas, usa, australian-citizens, cuba, customs-and-immigration

We are Australians planning a trip to Cuba. We can now fly direct from LA but are worried that we might not be allowed to board, even with a visa. Dies anyone know the current situation?

Comment: LA  Louisiana? Los Angeles?      Latvia?